# Questions about Linux pipes and notifications

Tags: notifications, pipe, kernel, child-process

Assume a terminal emulator, conceptually reading input from a KBD, appending that input to a visible transcript and also writing it into a pipe which is supplying stdin to child processes.  Further, assume that the emulator is implemented as poll loop.

- Can I get notified when the pipe becomes empty?
- If not, is there a way to query the pipe to determine whether is has become empty?
- Is there a way to query the pipe to determine whether it has a reader pending?

Ideally, I would like poll to inform me, not when there is some space in the pipe, but rather, when (1) the pipe is empty AND (2) when there is a reader process or thread pending.  I know that poll cannot do that today.  For a first foray into kernel hacking, how hard would it be to add a new poll events/revents mask to implement such functionality?

Comment: Do not EVER think of kernel modifications as your first step to a solution.  If it were needed, it would already be there.  You can do a non-blocking read to see if the pipe is empty, but it is a much better practice to design your code so that you don't care.  When there is work to do, you do it.  When there is no work to do, you block.  That's why the design is the way it is.

Comment: I want to implement Apollo Computer's Display Manager input/transcript pairs.

The distinguishing characteristic of a DM transcript was that, even in the presence of typeahead, it recorded faithfully and immutably, from the child process's perspective, the interleaving of input consumed from stdin with output written to stdout. (Of course, in the absence of typeahead, creating such a transcript is trivial.)

The essential implementation hurdle then is handling typeahead. And that comes down to being able to ask whether the pipe supplying stdin is both (1) empty and (2) has a read waiting.

Comment: @tim-roberts, I too have been programming since the Nixon era, and still do professionally. In my time I have built real time process control system in assembler, multiple compilers, databases, file system, etc.  Asserting that "If it were needed, it would already be there" is silly.  Were that true there would be no kernel evolution. My realistic expectation is that (1) I could get my poll extension to work, (2) no one would be interested without a compelling use case. Explaining the Apollo DM's transcripts is too hard. Building a working example within emacs seems the most compelling route.

Comment: I can't help but think you are over-complicating this.  Are you just saying the transcript does buffering to ensure the echoed input is properly interleaved with the output?  That's easily handled with a library.

Comment: The transcript is simply a passive log. It is intended to be a properly interleave record, from the POV of child processes, of (1) output delivered to stdout and (2) input read from stdin. The child process POV is crucial and it what make the transcript so valuable.

Comment: The transcript is a passive log, intended to be a properly interleaved record, from the POV of child processes, of (1) child output delivered to stdout and (2) child input read from stdin. The child process POV is crucial. It is what makes a transcript so valuable.

The terminal emulator writes child output to the transcript immediately. It buffers typeahead (and exposes it for editing in a typeahead pane) but only delivers a line of typeahead when it know that (1) the pipe to the child is empty and (2) that a child is actually waiting. It also writes that line of input to the transcript.

Comment: And where do you expect to intercede for this?  Where does your code live?  If you have a library in the target process, this is trivially easy, right?  You just intercept reads from stdin and writes to stdout.